# Getting error while running the web app after creating nabber

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I get the following error once I run the *localhost:3000/home.js* file

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstName')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstName')
    at Navbar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:520:28)
```

I can't find the error neither the bundle.js file and don't know what is the prob with firstName

Comment: why is this error showing as I checked with mongo db and it is connected